# Full Adder output always set to X

Tags: system-verilog, fpga, hdl, vivado

I am starting in FPGA coding, and one of my first exercises is to code a full adder.  I am using SystemVerilog to code within Vivado.  My take on this is as follow:

Source:

```
`timescale 1ns/10ps
module challenge
  (
   input  wire  [2:0]    SW,
   output logic [1:0]    LED
   );
  assign LED[0]=SW[1]^SW[0]^SW[2]; // Write the code for the Sum
  assign LED[1]=(SW[1]&SW[0])|((SW[1]^SW[0])&SW[2]); // Write the code for the Carry
endmodule // challenge
```

TestBench:

```
`timescale 1ns/100ps
module tb;

  logic [2:0] SW;
  logic [1:0] LED;

  challenge u_challenge (.*);

  // Stimulus
  initial begin
    $printtimescale(tb);
    SW = '0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) begin
      $display("Setting switches to %3b", i[2:0]);
      SW  = i[2:0];
      #100;
    end
    $display("PASS: logic_ex test PASSED!");
    $stop;
  end

  logic [2:0] sum;
  assign sum = SW[0] + SW[1] + SW[2];
  // Checking
  always @(SW, LED) begin
    if (sum !== LED[0]) begin
      $display("FAIL: Addition mismatch");
      $stop;
    end
  end 
endmodule // tb
```

No matter what I put from `SW` into `LED` (any combination of SW[0],SW[1],SW[2]), I will always have my `LED` values set to X.
Is there a problem with my definition of `SW`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of `SW` looks fine.

I removed the `$stop` calls from your code so the simulation would run to completion.  Using `$stop` halts your simulation and sets it to interactive mode.  Perhaps Vivado is waiting for you to enter commands before it updates your output.

I copied your code onto [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/RBXN), and it runs fine.  I don't see X in the waveforms.

[image: waves]

Here is the output I see:

```
Setting switches to 001
FAIL: Addition mismatch
Setting switches to 010
Setting switches to 011
FAIL: Addition mismatch
FAIL: Addition mismatch
Setting switches to 100
FAIL: Addition mismatch
Setting switches to 101
FAIL: Addition mismatch
FAIL: Addition mismatch
Setting switches to 110
FAIL: Addition mismatch
Setting switches to 111
FAIL: Addition mismatch
FAIL: Addition mismatch
PASS: logic_ex test PASSED!
```

Comment: Silly mistake from my end. Removing those  stop  did the trick.Thanks a lot

Answer (score -3):

I think you can add some wait times before the check.

```
  // Checking
  always @(SW, LED) begin
    #50;
    if (sum !== LED) begin
      $display("FAIL: Addition mismatch");
      $stop;
    end
  end
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.  It has the same problem as in the question.  Did you see the other answer?